# Cannot install package in Umbraco - getting a 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I have installed Umbraco 7.10.0 via NuGet in VS2017 and run the site with IISExpress. What I would like now, is an editor which supports mathematical formulas.

Fortunately there is an editor called uCKEditor with a plugin for [mathematical formulas](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/mathjax) - just what I need. On their site, they advise to use the so called "Online builder" to automatically get uCKEditor + math plugin + dependencies. So I did, and downloaded the zip package.

From there I go to install the package. Thus in Umbraco backoffice I go to Developer -> Packages -> Install local, and point to the zip file I just downloaded.

*This gives the error "Request error: The URL returned a 404 (not found): /umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/PackageInstall/UploadLocalPackage"*

[image]

What can be the reason for this problem, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

the maths plugin you've found is specifically a ckEditor plugin, not an Umbraco plugin and therefore Umbraco doesn't know what to do with it.

You need to read the ckEditor widget installation guide and install that plugin according to their instructions:

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_widget_installation.html